# Display the values of one specific item in React when clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My application has a list of users.

Each user has a certain number of blogs with a title, author and url.

My current app shows a list of all the users like so:

User 1 : blogs: 2 SHOW 
User 2 : blogs: 8 SHOW 
etc.

When clicking the show button, the page should render the details of THAT specific user's blogs like so:

User 1's blogs:

Title1 
Title2 
etc.

When implementing my current solution, when clicking the show button - the user gets directed to User 1's details ONLY, even when clicking on User 2, User 3, or User 4... it always goes back to User 1

How do you make it that when you click on SHOW for User 1 it goes to user 1, SHOW for user 2 it goes to user 2 etc. I think the issue is with the HANDLECLICK.

```
import userService from '../services/users'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'


    const User = () => {
    
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
         
    const handleClick = () => {
        users.map(u => setUsers([u]))
        }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        userService
          .getAll()
          .then(users => {
            setUsers(users)
          })
      }, [])
    
      console.log(users)
    
      const blogStyle = {
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingLeft: 2,
        border: "solid",
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginBottom: 5,
      };
    
      if (!users) {
        return null
      }
    
      if (users.length === 1) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{users.map(u => u.username)}'s entries</h2>
                {users.map(u => u.blogs.map(u => <li key={u.id} style={blogStyle}>{u.title}</li>))}
            </div>
        )
      }
    
    
    
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Users</h2>
                <ul>
                    {users.map(u => <li key={u.id} style={blogStyle}>{u.username}: {u.blogs.length}<button onClick={handleClick}>Show</button></li>)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default User
```

Services:

```
import axios from "axios";
const baseUrl = "/api/users";

const getAll = () => {
    const request = axios.get(baseUrl);
    return request.then((response) => response.data);
  };

  export default { getAll }
```

Users

```
[{"title":"Blog Title","author":"J John","url":"www.url.com","id":"628f998a532016f769978e95","likes":0},{"title":"Blog Title","author":"J John","url":"www.url.com","user":{"username":"root","name":"Superuser","id":"628f969252b604bdb13b672e"},"id":"628f9b685bfa95ded0cb29cf","likes":0},{"title":"Blog Title","author":"J John","url":"www.url.com","user":{"username":"root","name":"Superuser","id":"628f969252b604bdb13b672e"},"id":"6298ba4da20133b892443f75","likes":0},{"title":"Passwords and tokens","author":"I Fleming","url":"www.iiii.com","user":{"username":"testuser","name":"testuser","id":"6298bef3c00dbef70a9f3c55"},"id":"6298cc365935ee8f873dd2cf","likes":0},{"title":"jjj","author":"jjj","url":"jjj","user":{"username":"jjj","name":"jjj","id":"629b18d3272af122ea7830f2"},"id":"629b194c5ad19d29b2d30910","likes":0},{"title":"You","author":"Program","url":"www.kkk.com","user":{"username":"kkk","name":"kkk","id":"629b19b15ad19d29b2d30915"},"id":"629b1a1e5ad19d29b2d3091d","likes":0},{"title":"Zoom","author":"Parzifal","url":"www.smorg.com","user":{"username":"kkk","name":"kkk","id":"629b19b15ad19d29b2d30915"},"likes":1,"id":"629b1b5fd8d110a6e5d4671e"},{"title":"Rank ","author":"J John","url":"www.rank.com","user":{"username":"mmm","name":"mmm","id":"629b5b62d2afb19a39515c77"},"id":"629f53295cfed3eca2683add","likes":0},{"title":"Test Title With Update","author":"J John","url":"www.title.com","user":{"username":"mmm","name":"mmm","id":"629b5b62d2afb19a39515c77"},"likes":3,"id":"62cc19b6df95af90c24418df"},{"title":"fdddd","author":"Daniel Harmann","url":"Daniel Harmann","user":{"username":"mmm","name":"mmm","id":"629b5b62d2afb19a39515c77"},"id":"62d1760131423c5391b17a91","likes":0}]
```

Comment: what it mean `const handleClick = () => {
        users.map(u => setUsers([u]))
        }`

Comment: you are taking `users` from `useState` and map through and set user. in this case you always get last one in  `users` const.

Comment: I see, that makes sense - any idea how to change handleClick so you get the correct user? i.e. User 1 SHOW button ---> user 1, user 2 SHOW button ---> user 2 etc. ?

Comment: This `Users` array doesn't fit render statement - for instance there's no `user.blogs` member

Comment: @JuliusGoddard instead of using `onClick={handleClick}` just pass `onClick={() => handlClick(u)}` and in handleClick use `setUsers([u])` to set.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to change the HandleClick to handleClick = (u) => setUsers([u])

and to change the onClick.

See the following below:

```
    import userService from '../services/users'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'


const User = () => {

const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
     
const handleClick = (u) => {
    setUsers([u])
    }

useEffect(() => {
    userService
      .getAll()
      .then(users => {
        setUsers(users)
      })
  }, [])

  console.log(users)

  const blogStyle = {
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingLeft: 2,
    border: "solid",
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 5,
  };

  if (!users) {
    return null
  }

  if (users.length === 1) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{users.map(u => u.username)}'s entries</h2>
            {users.map(u => u.blogs.map(u => <li key={u.id} style={blogStyle}>{u.title}</li>))}
        </div>
    )
  }



    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Users</h2>
            <ul>
                {users.map(u => <li key={u.id} style={blogStyle}>{u.username}: {u.blogs.length}<button onClick={() => handleClick(u)}>Show</button></li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default User
```